# Database is showing hebrew, but in php the hebrew data is showing as question marks

Tags: php, mysql, database, hebrew

Database is showing hebrew, but in php the hebrew data is showing as question marks.
My code is something like this(this is not the full code):

```
  <?php
    require('connect.php');
    $result = mysqli_query($con,"SELECT * FROM bookList ORDER BY title LIMIT 
    10");
    $row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result);
    $title = $row['title'];
    echo $title;
    ?>
```

Comment: use `mysqli_set_charset()`  http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.set-right after the `mysqli_connect()` .. PHP MySQL client connections defaults to a latin1 charset.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check your character encoding is consistently UTF-8 everywhere.

- Check the DB is utf-8
- Check the table is utf-8
- check the column is utf-8
- check the html meta tag charset is utf-8
- check in your IDE or text editor that the PHP file is utf-8.